# Pick out peak busy times from a sqldate field in MS Power BI

Tags: datetime, powerbi

I am trying to analyse sql data based on a date-time  field so I can know when  the peak times are for phone calls. Creating a view in sql server to pick out the times from the date-time field is easy enough, but I have been asked to do it in Microsoft BI. Does anyone have a quick solution for this? I was looking at using at tree visualisation, but please feel free to shoot me down for my naivete(?)

Thanks all....

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest bucketing your date-time values into appropriate intervals and plotting it as a bar graph like Google does for restaurant popular times:

[image: Peak Hours]